# sign extend 1-bit 2's complement number?

Tags: c, binary, twos-complement

I am a student and I am writing a function in C to sign extend a given bit field. I'm working with 32 bits.

I looked this answer up on Google but didn't find what I was looking for.

I'm writing function that returns the twos complemnt representation of one or more consecutive bits pulled from a 32 int. The leftmost bit is the sign bit.

What do I return if I pull a single bit? How do you represent a single bit as a signed twos complment number?

Comment: A single bit 2's-complement number can only be 0 or -1.

Comment: What Mystical says.  It's a somewhat absurd case, but consistent with the "specifications".

Comment: There's no sign extension that needs to be done. Just use the value.

Comment: @R -- you need the sign extension if the value is to be returned in, say, an int 32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense to talk a 1-bit two's complement number.  If you only have 1 bit, it is either 0 or 1.

In general, if you have a two's complement number with N bits, the highest value expressible is `2^(N-1)-1` and the lowest value is `-2^(N-1)`.  If we want to be silly we can apply this to N=1 and we find that a 1-bit two's complement number can range from -1 to 0.

**Edit:**  You wrote:

> I'm writing function that returns the twos complemnt representation of one or more consecutive bits pulled from a 32 int. The leftmost bit is the sign bit.

I don't think this is well defined.  *Two's complement* is an encoding that lets you represent a mathematical integer as a series of bits.  Given an integer, it tells you what bits to store.  I don't know what the two's complement representation of a series of bits would be.  It's like you're asking me to give you the ASCII encoding of a series of arbitrary bytes, or you are asking me to translate the Gettysburg Address from French to English.

Comment: It does make sense to talk about the 1-bit TC number as a sort of boundary condition, in the general case of N-bit TC numbers. One simply needs to understand that it's something of an absurd case.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to pluck N arbitrary bits (N >= 1 & <=32) from a bit stream in a 32-bit variable and represent them as a 2's complement number (presumably returning that number as a signed int 32).

What this says is that you take the selected bits, place them in the low-order (ie, right) end of a work variable, and then "extend" the left-most selected bit by propagating (copying) it leftward through the remaining (previously undefined) bits in the work variable.  This can be done as a single consistent algorithm, with no need to special-case any particular value of N.

For two bits it will produce the possible values 1, 0, -1, and -2 (for bit patterns 01, 00, 11, and 10 respectively).  For one bit it will produce the possible values 0 and -1 (for bit patterns 0 and 1 respectively).