# C programming bitfield in structure

Tags: c, structure, bit, bit-fields

Why is answer of it

```
-1, 2, -3 ?  (especially -3 ??? how come)

struct b1 {
    int a:1;
    int b:3;
    int c:4;
} ;
int  main()
{
    struct b1 c = {1,2,13};
    printf("%d, %d, %d",c.a,c.b,c.c);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled on VC++ 32 bit editor. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

signed integers are represented in twos complement. The range of a 1-bit twos complement number is -1 to 0. Because the first bit of a twos complement number indicates it is negative, which is what you have done there.

See here:
[sign extend 1-bit 2's complement number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240925/sign-extend-1-bit-2s-complement-number)

That is the same for the third number, you have overflowed the range of -8 to 7 which is the range of a 4 bit signed integer.

What you meant to do there is make all of those `int` -> `unsigned int`

See here for twos complement explanation:
http://www.ele.uri.edu/courses/ele447/proj_pages/divid/twos.html

Comment: can u please explain how come b1.c=-3 ?

Comment: To be pedantic, the C standard doesn't say anything about how negative integers are to be represented...

Comment: @KerrekSB §6.2.6.2 of the C11 spec at least mentions three possible alternatives (sign/magnitude, one's complement, two's complement) - not sure if this is a closed list, though

Comment: PowerPC, 13 is 1101, and to get the twos compliment of a number you flip the bits and add 1. So 0010 + 1 is 0011, this would be the positive number 3 and 1101 is the negative representation, I.e -3

Answer (score 2):

Because `a` and `c` are signed integers with their sign bit set, hence they are negative:

```
a:  1d =    1b (1 bit)
b:  2d =  010b (3 bits)
c: 13d = 1101b (4 bits)
```

Signed integer values are stored in two's complement, with the highest bit representing the sign  (1 means "negative"). Hence, when you read the bitfield values as signed int's, you get back negative values for `a` and `c` (sign extended and converted back from their two's complement representation), but a positive `2` for `b`.

To get the absolute value of a negative two's complement number, you subtract one and invert the result:

```
 1101b
-0001b
======
 1100b
```

`1100b` inverted becomes `0011b` which is equal to `3d`. Since the sign bit is negative (which you had to examine before doing the previous calculation anyway), the result is `-3d`.

Comment: can u please explain how come b1.c=-3 ?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but it is difficult to digest :)