# Does the bit field correspond to registers in the accumulator?

Tags: c, bit-fields

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 struct byte
 {
 int one:1;
 };
 struct byte var = {1};
 printf("%d\n", var.one);
 return 0;
}
```

**Things I understood:**

- : is the bit field operator. `int one :1;` means create variable `one` with memory of 1 bit.

-`struct byte var = {1};`  tries to put 1 in variable one.

**What I did not understand**

- why the output is zero when I put `struct byte var = {even_number};`
- why the output is -1 when I put `struct byte var = {odd_number};`

My analogy is that somehow the negative flag(7th flag) become high/1 and gives -1. But I have no proof.I think there must be some other logic. But, Does the bit field correspond to registers in the accumulator?

Comment: Because in a 2 to complement enumeration system to set the higher bit indicates negative numbers ... :p ... If you want 0 and 1 try to use `unsigned int one:1`.

Comment: [Bit Fields in C](//stackoverflow.com/q/31026471)

Comment: @SirJoBlack sorry, but I didn't quite understand that. Can you explain

Comment: If you use a `short int a=0x8000` the value of a shall be a negative number and all the number having the higher bit set shall be negative number.

Comment: @Vedantkarandikar. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: And the structure's variable `one` has only size of 1 bit. Meaning you can store only `0` or `1`.

Comment: @J...S you're implying the `unsigned` type, which is not true in this case.

Comment: It is not specified by C what `int:1` means, so the output can be any random crap. The solution is to never use bit-fields, because they are so unreliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you declared the bit field as `int`, which is signed.

Assuming [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of negative numbers, that means that if the highest bit is set then the number is negative.  And since the field only has 1 bit, setting this bit gives you a negative number, i.e. -1.

If you want to store 0 or 1 in this field, you need to declare it as `unsigned int` and subsequently use the `%u` format specifier to print it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   struct byte
   {
     unsigned int one:1;
   };
   struct byte var = {1};
   printf("%u\n", var.one);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't specified. You make it sound as if the `int` version of the program has well-defined behavior - it has not. This is listed as implementation-defined behavior. See C11 Annex J.3.9, for some documentation over how useless bit-fields are. Notably: `Whether a "plain" int bit-field is treated as a signed int bit-field or as an unsigned int bit-field (6.7.2, 6.7.2.1).`

Answer (score 1):

A one-bit long storage of `signed` type is only good enough to hold two values ([in 2's complement format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)), i.e., `0` and `-1`.

If you want to have a value of `1`, you need the bit-field set to 2, at least.

Otherwise, if you don;t want to deal with `-`ve values, (or, in general) it's a good idea to make use of `unsigned` type, while using bit-fields.

Comment: I thought one bit could store 0 and 1 . because it is 2^0

Comment: @Vedantkarandikar nope, check 2's complement.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Can you clarify something for me? There's only one bit. If that bit itself is considered the sign bit, how does the compiler know it's `1`? I mean the value is obtained from the rest of the bits, right?

Comment: @J...S In 2's complement, the high bit being set indicates the value is negative, but it is not a sign bit.  Adding 1 to this bit pattern gives 0, which is the correct result.

Comment: @J...S  that is what he is trying to explain. it is not the sign bit. it stored the values. But when storing in form of 2s complement, you can only store it as 0 and -1 .

Comment: @J...S Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240960/2173917), _"if you have a two's complement number with N bits, the highest value expressible is 2^(N-1)-1 and the lowest value is -2^(N-1). If we want to be silly we can apply this to N=1 and we find that a 1-bit two's complement number can range from -1 to 0."_

Comment: @J...S  2s complement of 0  is -1 and of 1 is 1. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Vedantkarandikar 2's complement of 0 must be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Because of `:1`, a variable of type `struct byte` stores only one bit of information (please note the misleading name).

The field `one` of a variable of type `struct byte` is initialized with the rightmost bit of the initializer value, i.e. `0` for even numbers and `1` for odd numbers. All the other bits are ignored.

But the type of the `one` property is `int`, (i.e. signed). The values it can stored into a signed integer of `n` bits belong to the interval `-2`<sup>`n-1`</sup> .. `2`<sup>`n-1`</sup>`-1`.

In your example, `n` is `1` and the interval of values is `-1..0`. The rightmost bit is also the leftmost bit and, when stored in 2-complement, `1` is the bit representation of the signed integer `-1`.